# How can I ensure UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification in iOS 6?

Tags: ios

I want to stop the `AVAssetWriter` session just before the application is terminated. How can I ensure `UIApplicationWillTerminateNotification` will be called when the user terminates the app manually or the OS terminates the app to free up memory for other apps?

I don't care about termination due to a memory warning, only cases where the app has already been sent to the background.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you explicitly set your application not to run in background (by setting the 'Application does not run in background' key) whenever the user press the Home button your application will be terminated and it will receive the `applicationWillTerminate:` message.

However, if your application doesn't set this key it'll probably never get the `applicationWillTerminate:` message because by the time it gets terminated by the system, it will already have been suspended. In this case consider stopping your `AVAssetWriter` in the `applicationDidEnterBackground:` method.

Hope this helps!

Comment: How to handle this notification as relaunching the application is preserving its state and getting crashed after few seconds.????

Comment: What error messages are you getting? What is your use-case? What code do you have to handle the notification? Please consider creating a new question so I can help you better.

Answer (score 2):

You can't. The application decides when it's sent and it often won't be sent at all.

If you're running in the background you should do all of your cleanup in the expiration handler. You can also use `backgroundTimeRemaining` to know when you're going to get terminated.